# Cannot GET /implicit/callback

Tags: reactjs, okta

I am integrating okta in my react application for SSO, I followed steps mentioned in okta developer's guide

Here is my index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Security, ImplicitCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';
import HomePage from './components/home/HomePage';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const config = {
  issuer: 'https://XXX.oktapreview.com',
  redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback',
  client_id: '0oxxxxxxxxxxxxx7'
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Security issuer={config.issuer}
                  client_id={config.client_id}
                  redirect_uri={config.redirect_uri}
        >
          <Route path='/' exact={true} component={HomePage}/>
          <Route path='/implicit/callback' component={ImplicitCallback}/>
        </Security>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

constantly getting Cannot GET /implicit/callback.
My app configuration in okta is like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63gOK.png)

I am guessing something wrong with webpack config.

Comment: Please post all your code.

Comment: updated details let me know if you need something else.

Answer (score 0):

looks like issue with webpack only, when i removed , `publicPath: '/'` it worked locally atleast but still not on production environment

```
output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "index_bundle.js",
        publicPath: '/',
        crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous'
    }
```

Has someone faced this before?

Answer (score -1):

The `/implicit/callback` is just another route. You could just add google.com and it will redirect to that. This is my component from Okta react sample and it works. hope it helps

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Security, SecureRoute, ImplicitCallback } from '@okta/okta-react';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import Protected from './Protected';
import Sprotected from './Sprotected';

function onAuthRequired({history}) {
  history.push('/login');
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Security issuer='https://mytrainingcompany.okta.com/oauth2/default'
                  client_id='0oa88p4tcET4KPJwg2p6'
                  redirect_uri={window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback'}
                  onAuthRequired={onAuthRequired} >
          <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home} />
          <SecureRoute path='/protected' component={Protected} />
          <SecureRoute path='/pro' component={Sprotected} />
          <Route path='/login' render={() => <Login baseUrl='https://mytrainingcompany.okta.com' />} />
          <Route path='/implicit/callback' component={ImplicitCallback} />
        </Security>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```